# How to calculate the file download size amount already downloaded out of the total size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
{
    string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
    string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
    string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
    string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
    
    string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s
    lblDownloadProgress.Text = progress;
    textProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    textProgressBar1.CustomText = progress;
}
```

I can see with a break point that the variable value of `e.BytesReceived` and `e.TotalBytesToReceive` are changing but on the progress variable the `downloadedMBs` and `totalMBs` values are 0 all the time.

Edit:
Example for values that cause the problem:
`e.BytesReceived`: 2196
`e.TotalBytesToReceive`: 194899

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360944/force-gui-update-from-ui-thread  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959185/gui-not-updating-until-code-is-finished

Comment: @wohlstad for example the first time the value of TotalBytesToReceive is 194899 and the value of BytesReceived is 2196

Comment: @BenBenShmil these values (194899 , 2196)  when divided by (1024*1024) yield a result less than 0.5, and therefore rounded to 0. You can keep the calculations in `double`s if you want a more precise measurement report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you reported for both `e.TotalBytesToReceive` (**194899**) and `e.BytesReceived` (**2196**) are less than a half of **1024.0*1024.0==1048576.0**.

Therefore when you divide them twice by **1024.0**
(equivalent to dividing by **1024.0*1024.0==1048576.0**) you get a value less than **0.5**, and when rounded using `Math.Round` will give **0**.

You can either keep all the calculations in `double`s, or **specify the number of digits** after the decimal point you are interested in, as a second argument to `Math.Round`.
See in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.6#system-math-round(system-decimal-system-int32)).

For example if you are interested in `3` digits after the decimal point, you can use:

```
long bytesReceived = 2196;
long totalBytesToReceive = 194899;

//------------------------------------------------------------------V--------------------
string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(bytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0,  3).ToString() + " MB";
string totalMBs = Math.Round(totalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0, 3).ToString() + " MB";

Console.WriteLine("downloadedMBs: " + downloadedMBs);
Console.WriteLine("totalMBs: " + totalMBs);
```

Output:

```
downloadedMBs: 0.002 MB
totalMBs: 0.186 MB
```